# Why are tokens wrapped by parentheses not r-value expressions?

Tags: c++, parentheses, rvalue

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  Foo() : bar( 0 ) {}

  int bar;
};


int main()
{
  Foo foo;

  ++(foo.bar);

  std::cout<< foo.bar << std::endl;

  system("pause");
  return 0;
};
```

Why does `foo.bar` evaluate to 1?

Doesn't the parentheses in `(foo.bar)` create an unnamed (r-value) expression which is then incremented?

Comment: No, are you confusing this with some other language where `f(x)` and `f((x))` are different?

Comment: @BoPersson But there are some contexts where it makes a difference. For example `decltype(x)` and `decltype((x))` can be different.

Comment: @juanchopanza: damned... that's tricky!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the standard explicitly states that in 3.4.2 para 6:

> A parenthesized expression is a primary expression whose type and
>   value are identical to those of the enclosed expression. **The presence
>   of parentheses does not affect whether the expression is an lvalue.**

emphasis mine.

Comment: I was confused, because: `struct Widget{} w;` -> `decltype(w)` and `decltype((w))` are not the same.
See also [link](https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=F1B8FF18A2AEC5C5!1062), slide 33.

Comment: @user1787909: `decltype` is special.

Answer (score 1):

No, parenthesis do not have any meaning besides changing the order of operations.

To create an rvalue you need to use special function `std::move(x)`.

Comment: you may want to create a new stackoverflow question on that.

Comment: Is it so difficult to unabbreviate here?

Comment: adl = argument dependent name lookup

Comment: in an effort to improve the stackoverflow database, i have come to not answer comment questions anymore.